# React Router V4 redirecting on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-v4

I'm currently in development mode, so I'm refreshing pages constantly. I've a change to my app that is my browser to redirect to the default webpage each time the page is refreshed. Obviously, this is extremely annoying. In the example below if I refresh `/candidate/all_jobs` it redirects to `/candidate`.

I've been trying to figure out what I've changed but I can't seem to narrow it down. Any suggestions. I'm using:
Meteorjs
React
React-Router V4

Path: `isPublic.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const IsPublic = ({ loggingIn, isCandidate, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (isCandidate) {
        return (!isCandidate) ?
        (<Component loggingIn={loggingIn} isCandidate={isCandidate} {...rest} />) :
        (<Redirect to="/candidate" />);
      }

      if (!isCandidate) {
        return (<Component loggingIn={loggingIn} isAdmin={isAdmin} isCandidate={isCandidate} isEmployer={isEmployer} isEmployerButAccountNotActive={isEmployerButAccountNotActive} {...rest} />)
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

Path: `App.jsx`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

const App = appProps => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <div>
        <div className="container">
        <NavBar {...appProps} />

          <div className="container margin-bottom-container">
            <Switch>
              {/* candidate routes */}
              <IsCandidate exact path="/candidate" component={CandidateProfileContainer} {...appProps} />
              <IsCandidate exact path="/candidate/all_jobs" component={AllJobsContainer} {...appProps} />

              {/* IsPublic routes */}
              <IsPublic exact path="/login" component={Login} {...appProps} />

            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
);

App.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  isCandidate: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withTracker(() => {
  const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();
  const user = Meteor.user();

  let candidateHasCompletedRegistrationProcess;

  let loadingProfileAccount;

  if (!!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isCandidate')) {
    const profileAccountHandle = Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate.candidateUserData');
    loadingProfileAccount = !profileAccountHandle.ready();

    const candidateCompletedRegistrationProcess = user.candidateCompletedRegistrationProcess;

    if (candidateCompletedRegistrationProcess === true) {
      candidateHasCompletedRegistrationProcess = !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId() && !!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'isCandidate');
    }
  }

  return {
    loggingIn,
    loadingProfileAccount,
    isCandidate: !!candidateHasCompletedRegistrationProcess
  };
})(App);
```

Comment: `if (isCandidate) { return (!isCandidate) ? ..` will redirect every time if `isCandidate` is true?

Comment: Oh, well that's correct, but it's not what I intended. It is supposed to do that only on login. How can I get to only redirect if that's the case?

Comment: Returning the Redirect is what causes the redirect. Just re-work your logic in `IsPublic`'s render so that it does what you want.